# Product Import > URLs missing ".htm" extension even after re-indexing.

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport, url-key

I am uploading a large number products. The upload runs perfectly but Magento is not adding the file extension to the url_key. So none of the products uploaded have the “.htm” file extension. Even after indexing. I’ve tried everything I can think of to resolve this. I’m using version 1.9.4. This is driving me crazy. I've tried running the import without passing the url_key and the url_path. Magento creates the url with the product name and still no ".htm" extension as configured in the SEO settings.

Answer (score 0):

To make product URL with some particular extension, you need to indicate necessary URL suffix in Magento admin settings. Open `System-> Configuration -> Catalog-> Search Engine Optimization` and specify .htm in 'Category URL Suffix' field.

Flush Magento cache and perform re-index procedure.

Comment: So finding clear and detailed instructions on how to import into magento has been very challenging. I finally understand that even though the url_key field does not show the .htm extension, magento does in fact present the page with extension through the rewrite. Thank you Lillian. This was a lot of work to figure this out since there was nothing I could find that explicitly described how the url_key field is rewritten.